# How to get network path of a directory using command line

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell-3.0, nsis

Say I have a directory called `Temp` in windows.

[image]

When I right click on it and open properties, and go to `Sharing` tab, I see this:

[image]

The field `Network Path` is `Not Shared`.

Now I click `Share` and select to share with and click ok.

The field `Network Path` now has value:

[image]

Is there a way to get the value of `Network Path` from command line.

Ideally I am looking for a command which takes directory path as input e.g. `C:\Temp` and output `\\S5XXXXXXN\Temp` if the directory is shared or `Not Shared` if the directory is not shared.

**Background:**  I have a NSIS script to create an installer. The end of installation process is supposed to spit out a list of properties. One of the properties required for output is the `Network Path` of a directory. Inside NSIS what I have available is `C:\Temp` which I want to convert to `\\S5XXXXXXN\Temp` (if available) before spitting it out.

I tried to use this https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Get_Universal_Name  but its not working.

```
DetailPrint "My directory is:"
# value of MYDIR is C:\Temp
DetailPrint $MYDIR
Push $MYDIR
Call get_universal_name
Pop $MYDIRNET
DetailPrint "My dir after call is: "
DetailPrint $MYDIRNET
# above also prints C:\Temp even though its shared and has value \\S5XXXXXXN\Temp
```

Update:

The answer below by @Anders works like a charm.

The list returned has an entry with blank `$3` though. Just to be aware of and to add a necessary check if required.

[image]

Comment: What is RequestExecutionLevel set to in your .nsi?

Comment: @Anders RequestExecutionLevel is set as admin in my .nsi

Comment: @Anders I tried using WNetGetUniversalNameA and WNetGetUniversalNameW as well like some thread suggests.. but no difference.. still the same result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_universal_name` calls `WNetGetUniversalName` and this function only supports mapped drive letters (`net.exe use` style). `WNetGetConnection` seems to have the same limitation. Even if this limitation did not exist it would still not work because [a process elevated with UAC does not share the net connections with non-elevated processes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/programs-may-be-unable-to-access-some-network-locations-after-you-turn-on-user-account-control-in-windows-vista-or-newer-operating-systems-a3dd1683-9769-8ae2-7ec7-eae45147280b).

Going the other way does seem to work, getting a list of shares and their local paths:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh

Section "Check shares"
System::Call 'NETAPI32::NetShareEnum(p0,i2,*p.r1,i-1,*i0r5,*i0,p0)i.r0'
${If} $0 = 0
    Push $1
    ${DoWhile} $5 <> 0
        System::Call '*$1(p.r2,i,p,i,i,i,p.r3,p,&l.r4)'
        IntPtrOp $1 $1 + $4
        System::Call '*$2(&w${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}.r2)'
        System::Call '*$3(&w${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}.r3)'
        System::Call 'NETAPI32::NetServerGetInfo(p0,i100,*p.r4)' ; Get computer name
        System::Call '*$4(i,w.s)'
        System::Call 'NETAPI32::NetApiBufferFree(p$4)'
        Pop $4
        DetailPrint "$3=\\$4\$2"
        ; ${If} $3 == "$MYDIR" ...TODO... ${EndIf}
        IntOp $5 $5 - 1
    ${Loop}
    System::Call 'NETAPI32::NetApiBufferFree(ps)'
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Works like a charm! thank you so much! one entry in the list has blank $3. Have updated my question to reflect that for someone who may use this in future.

Comment: A blank one is normal, IPC is special. The API really returns share=path and not everything has a path.